# File which is invoked by all users for new bash sessions

Tags: debian, bash, debian-stretch

I'd like to put code into a file, which when a new session is made is invoked for all users on a Debian system.

`/etc/profile` is only touched by login sessions.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman You mean this wall of text which I don't understand half of it? https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: You want to read the chapter on **Invocation** which explains exactly which files get loaded when bash is started, as a interactive (login) shell or not.

Comment: @HBruijn is correct. But I removed my comment referring to `man bash` because reading the Invocation section now, it seems that there's no system-wide file that's executed for non-login sessions. Sorry.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman No worries Andrew :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> File which is invoked by all users for new bash sessions

When you read the chapter on **Invocation** in the manual you'll know that there is no such file. https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

I don't have a Debian box at hand but it might be that Debian does something similar to what RHEL/CentOS do: by default those distro's deploy from `/etc/skell`  both a `~/.bash_profile` and a `~/.bashrc` to the users home directory.

When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell the `~/.bash_profile` should be loaded.

## /etc/skel/.bash_profile

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
```

When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`

By loading the `~/.bashrc` from  `~/.bash_profile` you get a file that will be loaded for both normal and login sessions.

## /etc/skel/.bashrc

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
```

The `~/.bashrc` in turn will load global `/etc/bashrc` and you get a system wide file that gets loaded for both login as well as non-login interactive bash sessions.